# Delphi 2009 - how can install the system library units - SysUtils.pas & so on?

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-2009, filesystems

I've installed RAD Studio 2009 for Delphi & I want to be able to step in the system library units, such as SysUtils.pas & alike, but it seems that they where not installed with the IDE.

Is there any installation option to do this? Appreciate any help with this issue.

Comment: Are you using the trial version? The sources are not included in this edition.

Answer (score 2):

I think there might be different editions, but if you have one where the source for those is included and assuming default directories, the files should be installed in

```
C:\Program Files\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\source\Win32\rtl\sys
```

To use them, you need to have "Use debug DCUs" checked in Project | Options | Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using trial version?

Trial doesn't install source (.pas) files (\source folder) - only precompiled .dcu-files (\lib and \lib\debug folders).

If you have bought usual version of Delphi (not trial) - then just run "Modify, Repair, Uninstall" and verify that all checkboxes are set.